# Can I host jQuery.js and jQuery.mobile.js on the assets folder in an Android web app project

Tags: android, cordova, android-webview

I'm write a Android web App Use jQuery mobile/HTML5/Use Phonegap/Eclipse/[jqmphp](http://www.jqmphp.com), jqmPhp is a package of PHP classes, it echo the HTML dom elsements, I see its source,

```
define('JQMPHP_JQM', 'http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a3/jquery.mobile-1.0a3.min.js', true);
```

But I want host the JavaScript and CSS in the APK file to reduce the HTTP request. How Can the HTTP web call the APK's resource?

Answer (score 1):

`assets/www/foo.js` -> `<script src="./foo.js"></script>`

Comment: but my php file is on the server side,'./foo.js'  means request the web roots file

Comment: do you not serve an index.html from 'assets/www/'?

Comment: yes.it seems I must creat the index.html file in the assets/www/ folder. it`s more complex than I thought。I need more study。thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can host the files in the android assets folder, just include the files in regular script tags in your index file.

Also, there are newer, more stable versions of jQueryMobile available.

Comment: I tried this using path "file:///android_asset/www/foo.js" but fail。

Comment: Use a relative path. So have it next to your index file and just include foo.js